# Use array_multisort to arrange arrays by date

Tags: php, arrays

I have built a group of arrays which I am trying to sort by 'start' date (HH:mm) using array_multisort. The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [start] => 13:00
    [end] => 14:00
    [title] => An event
    [day] => Monday
)
Array
(
    [start] => 00:00
    [end] => 06:00
    [title] => An event
    [day] => Monday
)
Array
(
    [start] => 06:00
    [end] => 13:00
    [title] => An event
    [day] => Monday
)
```

I would like to order these by 'start', so they should look like so:

```
Array
(
    [start] => 00:00
    [end] => 06:00
    [title] => An event
    [day] => Monday
)
Array
(
    [start] => 06:00
    [end] => 13:00
    [title] => An event
    [day] => Monday
)
Array
(
    [start] => 13:00
    [end] => 14:00
    [title] => An event
    [day] => Monday
)
```

I am attempting to do this using array_multisort. Below is my complete code. I have applied 'array_multisort' to $monday, but it is ignored. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
     if ($row['day'] == 'Monday') {
          $monday = array 
               (
        'start' => $row['start_time'],
        'end' => $row['end_time'],
        'title' => get_the_title(),
        'day' => $row['day'],
        );

     }
}

array_multisort($monday, SORT_ASC);     
print_r($monday);
```

Comment: You are overwriting $monday over and over, rather than adding to it, so there is nothing to sort. I think your intention was `$monday[] = array(...`

Comment: OK thanks, but when I use $monday[] it creates lots of parent arrays with repeated arrays within them

Comment: I don't understand. What structure is it that you actually want?

Comment: This is what print_r($rows) returns: http://pastebin.com/FnsQ2K4S. From this information I just want to retreive arrays with a day value of 'Monday' and I want the new array to be ordered by 'start' value. When I use the code in my above question and add the square brackets to $monday I get this: http://pastebin.com/NDdiCbYh but what I want is this: http://pastebin.com/J4dBS1FY

Comment: Your "wrong" output is actually just the "right" output displayed at multiple points in the program while it's being built.

Comment: I edited my answer, try that, it should do, what do you want

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function my_cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a["start"], $b["start"]);
}

usort($monday, "my_cmp");
```

---

**EDIT**

You should say what do you want...

This could make, what you except

```
$mondays = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $day) {
        if ($row['day'] == 'Monday') {
          $mondays[] = array(
                'start' => $row['start_time'],
                'end' => $row['end_time'],
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'day' => $row['day'],
          );

        }
     }
}

function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a["start"], $b["start"]);
}

usort($mondays, "cmp");
```

Comment: I get `Illegal string offset 'start'`

Comment: I am using Xampp which has 5.5.11

Comment: Now I get `Cannot redeclare cmp()` as well as `Illegal string offset 'start'`

Comment: it should work, do you coppy it correctly?
in witch line is error?

Comment: Yes, I copied it exactly, but I still get the same problems

Comment: that **Illegal string offset 'start'** is syntax error, it not in my code, it may be in different place

post line of your code, whitch give this error

Comment: Do you have any idea where? I cannot see any mistakes

Comment: The error `Illegal string offset 'start'` continues with line number, where is this error, so coppy me that line

Comment: It's not a syntax error, it's because $monday is just one event, not the array of arrays you intended it to be.

Comment: It says line 86 which is `return strcmp($a["start"], $b["start"]);`

Comment: Is it maybe because each array doesn't have a number on its parent? it just says Array() instead of Array [0] ()

Comment: @user1444027 it couldn't be that line

Comment: @Unlink Yes, it's that line. Try this, you should see that same error: `$foo = 'a string'; echo $foo['start'];` It's not a syntax error, just trying to treat something as an array which isn't one.